# CSS: select item by data-filter attribute

Tags: css, wordpress, list, filter, attributes

I have to remove certain items from a nav, which differ by their data-filter attribute. How can I refer to the specific list-items?
Such as, if I wanted to remove the item by data-filter ".category-xyz":

```
<li class="filter" data-filter=".category-xyz"><span>xyz</span></li>
```

I tried loads - all without any errors - nothing finds the specific list-item. I tried: (all each)

```
.filter-holder ul:nth-child(3){
    display:none;
}

.filter .category-xyz{
    display: none;
}

.filter-holder ul li[data-filter*=".category-xyz"]{
display: none;
}

li[data-filter=".category-xyz"]{
    display:none;
}

.filter-holder ul li[data-filter|=category-xyz]{
display: none;
}
```

Somebody help?

Comment: See my answer. Is that what you wish to achieve ?

Comment: Ahh, I typed it wrong in here. In my original code, the <li> is closed.

Comment: UPDATE: the problem seems to be with "display:none;". I tried to make the elements' background blue - worked perfectly.
Switched background: blue; to display:none; --> nothing. 
FYI, it's wordpress!

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a `>` in your HTML after `xyz"`

Other than that, your last 3 CSS rules should work.

Here is a working [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/abrahammurciano/22vk1oka/).

```css
li[data-filter=".category-xyz"]{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="filter-holder">
  <ul>
    <li class="filter" data-filter=".category-xyz"><span>xyz</span></li>
    <li class="filter" data-filter=".category-abc"><span>abc</span></li>
    <li class="filter" data-filter=".category-xyz"><span>xyz</span></li>
    <li class="filter" data-filter=".category-abc"><span>abc</span></li>
    <li class="filter" data-filter=".category-xyz"><span>xyz</span></li>
    <li class="filter" data-filter=".category-abc"><span>abc</span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your `li` opening tag is incomplete without `>`
Use prefix selector.

```
element [attribute = "value"]{  
  /*code*/
}
```

```css
li[data-filter=".category-xyz"] {
  background: blue;
}
li {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<li class="filter" data-filter=".category-xyz">
  <span>
    xyz
  </span>
</li>
<li class="filter" data-filter=".NOTcategory-xyz">
  <span>
    xyz
  </span>
</li><li class="filter" data-filter=".NOTcategory-xyz">
  <span>
    xyz
  </span>
</li>
```

Comment: still no explanation

Comment: @dippas Satisfied ?

Comment: UPDATE: the problem seems to be with "display:none;". I tried to make the elements' background blue - worked perfectly.